# SSL and Http Proxy with java client issues - ConnectionClosedException

Tags: java, http, ssl, proxy, squid

We are using an http proxy server backing our java http client, which does hundreds of SSL requests per second.  The client is the AsyncHttpClient provided by netty, using NIO (com.ning:async-http-client:1.7.19).  The proxy server is using Squid 3.3.

When we have the client configured to 'allowSslConnectionPool', we frequently see java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException inside the NettyAsyncHttpProvider (we tried Grizzly which exhibited similar problems).  When we disable the ssl connection pooling, everything works fine.  Conversely, with pooling enabled and NO proxy server, things work fine again.  Obviously, the problem without pooling connections is that we create new SSL connections for every request severely impacts our servers.

Is there some fundamental problem with locally pooling SSL connections in a client and using an HTTPS Proxy?  It seems that there should be some setting to enable this to work, either on Squid or in the client itself, but we are at a loss at the moment.

**Client config**:

```
new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setMaximumConnectionsTotal(maxconns.get())
    .setMaximumConnectionsPerHost(consPerHost.get())
    .setUserAgent(userAgent.get())
    .setConnectionTimeoutInMs(MAX_CONN_TIME_MS)
    .setRequestTimeoutInMs(MAX_RESP_TIME_MS)
    .setFollowRedirects(true)
    .setAllowSslConnectionPool(true)
    .setProxyServer(new ProxyServer(ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTPS, "xxx", 3128, "yyy", "zzz")
    )
```

**The exception we get is**:

```
2013-08-02 09:33:33,342 DEBUG (New I/O worker #16 ) com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider: Unexpected I/O exception on channel [id: 0xd9cce308, xxx => yyy]
2013-08-02 09:33:33,343 DEBUG (New I/O worker #16 ) com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider:
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$6.run(SslHandler.java:1580)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper.run(ChannelRunnableWrapper.java:40)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.executeInIoThread(AbstractNioWorker.java:71)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.executeInIoThread(NioWorker.java:36)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.executeInIoThread(AbstractNioWorker.java:57)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.executeInIoThread(NioWorker.java:36)
```

**Relevant Squid config (we have tried with and without ssl-bump)**:

```
http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid3/server.crt key=/etc/squid3/server.key
always_direct allow all
ssl_bump allow all
```